# Zsh taking too long to launch on Fedora 38

Tags: terminal, zsh

I recently switched the default shell on my laptop to Z shell. However it randomly takes too long to launch, like 3-10 seconds at a time. I know this is not the norm especially from my experience running bash. I have checked .zshrc and there's just the normal config files there for oh-my-zsh. Nothing that should slow the terminal this much. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: oh-my-zsh is not *normal*. That's third party stuff with many often heavy modules some of which you may have enabled. Try starting it as `PS4='+[%D{%T.%.}]%N:%i> ' zsh -x` within `script` to capture the output to see where the time is spent.

Comment: Let me try it. Only issue is that it's happens randomly. I can't tell what causes it.

Comment: See  also https://stevenvanbael.com/profiling-zsh-startup

Comment: In any case, if you find out what caused your start up delay, please answer your own question here with how you determined it, what it was and how you fixed it so it can help others in a similar situation.

Comment: I have come to understand it's only when it's a cold start. First time I open the terminal after restarting the laptop. I believe it's a configuration issue, I'll update once I figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `oh-my-zsh` setup specifically, the multiple aliases. I removed it and the issue was gone. Still using `oh-my-zsh`.